# Фильтр feComposite не работает

Tags: svg, svg-filter

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' viewBox='0 0 400 400' style='border: 1px solid black;';>

<filter id="myFilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
        x="10" y="10" width="186" height="200">
  <feImage xlink:href="#MyImage1" result="pict1"/>
  <feImage xlink:href="#MyImage2" result="pict2"/>
  <feComposite in="pict1" in2="pict2" operator="in"/>
</filter>


<image id="MyImage1" x="30" y="10" 
       width="186" height="125" xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"/>
<image id="MyImage2" x="10" y="10" 
       width="186" height="125" xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"/>


</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверил много источников, где-то фильтр `feComposite` работает в комбинации с другими фильтрами, как например здесь:

```js
function startAnimation() {
  anim.beginElement()
}
```

```css
path {
  filter: url(#green-fill);
}
```

```html
<svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30 25.54" width="100px" height="100px">
  <defs>
    <filter id="green-fill" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#fff" />
      <feOffset dx="0">
        <animate id="anim" attributeName="dx" from="0" to="85" dur="5s" begin="indefinite" />
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <path fill="#ea0097" d="M12.41,4.67a8,8,0,0,0-7.89,8.18A8,8,0,0,0,12.41,21a7.64,7.64,0,0,0,5-1.83l6.22-6.34L17.39,6.5a7.73,7.73,0,0,0-5-1.83m0,20.95A12.61,12.61,0,0,1,0,12.85,12.61,12.61,0,0,1,12.41.07a12.21,12.21,0,0,1,8,3l0.14,0.13L30,12.85l-9.62,9.79a12.23,12.23,0,0,1-8,3"
  />
</svg>
<button onclick="startAnimation()">start Animation</button>
```

Но примеры, подобные вашему вопросу, где должно происходить взаимодействие двух изображений на настоящий момент или работают с ошибками или вообще не работают. С чем это связано, не понятно. Может очередные "улучшения" браузеров это вызвало. Раньше это всё работало, что видно по многочисленным примерам.
 В частности, [не работает, как ожидалось, пример](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters#feCompositeElement) **W3C**

Должно быть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас это в Firefox выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Chrome лучше, но тоже с ошибками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Пример W3C фильтр feComposite**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="330" height="195" viewBox="0 0 1100 650" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <title>Example feComposite - Examples of feComposite operations</title>
  <desc>Four rows of six pairs of overlapping triangles depicting
        the six different feComposite operators under different
        opacity values and different clearing of the background.</desc>
 <defs>
    <desc>Define two sets of six filters for each of the six compositing operators.
          The first set wipes out the background image by flooding with opaque white.
          The second set does not wipe out the background, with the result
          that the background sometimes shines through and is other cases
          is blended into itself (i.e., "double-counting").</desc>
    <filter id="overFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="over" result="comp"/>
      <feMerge> <feMergeNode in="flood"/> <feMergeNode in="comp"/> </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <filter id="inFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="in" result="comp"/>
      <feMerge> <feMergeNode in="flood"/> <feMergeNode in="comp"/> </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <filter id="outFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="out" result="comp"/>
      <feMerge> <feMergeNode in="flood"/> <feMergeNode in="comp"/> </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <filter id="atopFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="atop" result="comp"/>
      <feMerge> <feMergeNode in="flood"/> <feMergeNode in="comp"/> </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <filter id="xorFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="xor" result="comp"/>
      <feMerge> <feMergeNode in="flood"/> <feMergeNode in="comp"/> </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <filter id="arithmeticFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" 
            x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" result="comp"
                   operator="arithmetic" k1=".5" k2=".5" k3=".5" k4=".5"/>
      <feMerge> <feMergeNode in="flood"/> <feMergeNode in="comp"/> </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <filter id="overNoFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="over" result="comp"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="inNoFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="in" result="comp"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="outNoFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="out" result="comp"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="atopNoFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="atop" result="comp"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="xorNoFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="xor" result="comp"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="arithmeticNoFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" 
            x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" result="comp"
                   operator="arithmetic" k1=".5" k2=".5" k3=".5" k4=".5"/>
    </filter>
    <path id="Blue100" d="M 0 0 L 100 0 L 100 100 z" fill="#00ffff" />
    <path id="Red100" d="M 0 0 L 0 100 L 100 0 z" fill="#ff00ff" />
    <path id="Blue50" d="M 0 125 L 100 125 L 100 225 z" fill="#00ffff" fill-opacity=".5" />
    <path id="Red50" d="M 0 125 L 0 225 L 100 125 z" fill="#ff00ff" fill-opacity=".5" />
    <g id="TwoBlueTriangles">
      <use xlink:href="#Blue100"/>
      <use xlink:href="#Blue50"/>
    </g>
    <g id="BlueTriangles">
      <use transform="translate(275,25)" xlink:href="#TwoBlueTriangles"/>
      <use transform="translate(400,25)" xlink:href="#TwoBlueTriangles"/>
      <use transform="translate(525,25)" xlink:href="#TwoBlueTriangles"/>
      <use transform="translate(650,25)" xlink:href="#TwoBlueTriangles"/>
      <use transform="translate(775,25)" xlink:href="#TwoBlueTriangles"/>
      <use transform="translate(900,25)" xlink:href="#TwoBlueTriangles"/>
    </g>
  </defs>

  <rect fill="none" stroke="blue" x="1" y="1" width="1098" height="648"/>
  <g font-family="Verdana" font-size="40" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
    <desc>Render the examples using the filters that draw on top of
          an opaque white surface, thus obliterating the background.</desc>
    <g enable-background="new">
      <text x="15" y="75">opacity 1.0</text>
      <text x="15" y="115" font-size="27">(with feFlood)</text>
      <text x="15" y="200">opacity 0.5</text>
      <text x="15" y="240" font-size="27">(with feFlood)</text>
      <use xlink:href="#BlueTriangles"/>
      <g transform="translate(275,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#overFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#overFlood)" />
        <text x="5" y="275">over</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(400,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#inFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#inFlood)" />
        <text x="35" y="275">in</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(525,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#outFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#outFlood)" />
        <text x="15" y="275">out</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(650,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#atopFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#atopFlood)" />
        <text x="10" y="275">atop</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(775,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#xorFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#xorFlood)" />
        <text x="15" y="275">xor</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(900,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#arithmeticFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#arithmeticFlood)" />
        <text x="-25" y="275">arithmetic</text>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0,325)" enable-background="new">
    <desc>Render the examples using the filters that do not obliterate
          the background, thus sometimes causing the background to continue
          to appear in some cases, and in other cases the background
          image blends into itself ("double-counting").</desc>
      <text x="15" y="75">opacity 1.0</text>
      <text x="15" y="115" font-size="27">(without feFlood)</text>
      <text x="15" y="200">opacity 0.5</text>
      <text x="15" y="240" font-size="27">(without feFlood)</text>
      <use xlink:href="#BlueTriangles"/>
      <g transform="translate(275,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#overNoFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#overNoFlood)" />
        <text x="5" y="275">over</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(400,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#inNoFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#inNoFlood)" />
        <text x="35" y="275">in</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(525,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#outNoFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#outNoFlood)" />
        <text x="15" y="275">out</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(650,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#atopNoFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#atopNoFlood)" />
        <text x="10" y="275">atop</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(775,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#xorNoFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#xorNoFlood)" />
        <text x="15" y="275">xor</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(900,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#arithmeticNoFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#arithmeticNoFlood)" />
        <text x="-25" y="275">arithmetic</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: если непонятно какие фильтры работают в разных браузерах их можно оставить ?

Comment: @Leks лучше конечно проверять, чтобы работало во всех браузерах, конечно об `IE` речь не идёт